# Inject Open XML into an Open PowerPoint Presentation

Tags: powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk, presentationml, drawingml

I'm looking for a way to inject **PresentationML** and/or **DrawingML** into an open PowerPoint 2007/2010 presentation using the Open XML SDK or just `System.IO.Packaging`. There is an article on [**doing this with Word**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191178.aspx), but in that example it is using the `Range.XML` routine in Word's object model, which I cannot find an equivalant for in PowerPoint's object model.

The reason I'm looking to do this is if I have an item on it that the PowerPoint client does not support editing of but that Open XML does (and as a result, PowerPoint will display it). I want to set this myself via a managed-addin (VSTO) on the open presentation. An example would be the underline of text (not that I'm looking for *this*, but it is an example) - in PowerPoint, you cannot make the underline of text a picture `<a:blip/>`, but in Open XML you can.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I am using both OpenXML SDK 2 and the Object Model to process presentations.
What I do, simplistic as it sounds, is to save the presentation, close it, perform all the XML modifications I need using OpenXML SDK, and then load the presentation back and continue with the Object Model.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, according to Microsoft support: http://www.ureader.com/msg/10972430.aspx